# Как залить не стандартную фигуру фоном или как обрезать фигуру нестандартно,а потом анимацией его двигать?

Tags: css

пробовал так,но картинку нельзя репитить и двигать ,чтоб капли скользили ,а фон можно,может еще есть какой вариант, пробовал через клипи паз но он не работает в ie подскажите

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" baseProfile="full"
    viewBox="0 0 346.92 153.83" width="700" height="700">

    <defs>
        <mask id="cat">

            <path
                d="M3.35,0,208.4,24,346.92,143.36l-1,1.37-236.64,9.1s-11-16.14-15.75-32.38S87.49,90,72,73.81,48.16,53.76,48.16,53.76,16.56,33.31,10.3,27.34-5,11.59,3.35,0Z"
                style="fill:white;stroke-width:1;stroke:white" />


        </mask>
    </defs>
    <image x="-90" y="0" width="700" height="700" xlink:href="http://placeimg.com/300/400/any" mask="url(#cat)">
    </image>
</svg>
```

```css
        .demo__target--before {
            background-color: teal;
            -webkit-clip-path: url(#clip-path-before);
            clip-path: url(#clip-path-before);
            background-position: -214px 602px;
        }

        .demo__target {
            width: 100%;
            height: 300px;
            background: url(https://source.unsplash.com/600x600?summer);
            background-size: cover;
        }
```

```html
 
     <svg>
        <clipPath id="clip-path-before" clipPathUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <path d="M3.35,0,208.4,24,346.92,143.36l-1,1.37-236.64,9.1s-11-16.14-15.75-32.38S87.49,90,72,73.81,48.16,53.76,48.16,53.76,16.56,33.31,10.3,27.34-5,11.59,3.35,0Z

">
    </svg>
    <div class="demo__target demo__target--before"></div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]